# $avg in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Document looks like this:

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("361de42f1938e89b179dda42"),
    "user_id" : "u1",
    "evaluator_id" : "e1",
    "candidate_id" : ObjectId("54f65356294160421ead3ca1"),
    "OVERALL_SCORE" : 150,
    "SCORES" : [ 
      { "NAME" : "asd", "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 30}, { "NAME" : "acd", "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 36}
      ]
   }
```

Aggregation function:

```
 db.coll.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$SCORES"}, {$group : { _id : { user_id : "$user_id", evaluator_id : "$evaluator_id"}, AVG_SCORE : { $avg : "$SCORES.OBTAINED_SCORE" }}} ])
```

Suppose if there are two documents with **same "user_id"** (say u1) and **different "evaluator_id"** (say e1 and e2).

For example:

1) Average will work like this ((30 + 20) / 2 = 25). This is working for me.

2) But for { evaluator_id : "e1" } document, **score is 30** for { "NAME" : "asd" } and { evaluator_id : "e2" } document, **score is 0** for { "NAME" : "asd" }. In this case, I want the **AVG_SCORE** to be **30 only (not (30 + 0) / 2 = 15)**.

Is it possible through aggregation??

Could any one help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by placing a **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** between the `$unwind` and `$group` aggregation pipelines to first filter the arrays which match the specified condition to include in the average computation and that is, score array where the obtained score is not equal to 0 `"SCORES.OBTAINED_SCORE" : { $ne : 0 }`

```
db.coll.aggregate([ 
    {
        $unwind: "$SCORES"
    },     
    { 
        $match : { 
            "SCORES.OBTAINED_SCORE" : { $ne : 0 } 
        } 
    },
    {
        $group : { 
            _id : { 
                user_id : "$user_id", 
                evaluator_id : "$evaluator_id"
            }, 
            AVG_SCORE : { 
                $avg : "$SCORES.OBTAINED_SCORE" 
            }
        }
     } 
 ])
```

For example, the aggregation result for this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5500aaeaa7ef65c7460fa3d9"),
    "user_id" : "u1",
    "evaluator_id" : "e1",
    "candidate_id" : ObjectId("54f65356294160421ead3ca1"),
    "OVERALL_SCORE" : 150,
    "SCORES" : [ 
        {
            "NAME" : "asd",
            "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "NAME" : "acd",
            "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 36
        }
    ]
}
```

will yield:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user_id" : "u1",
                "evaluator_id" : "e1"
            },
            "AVG_SCORE" : 36
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: One more case: If **both e1 and e2 gave score of 0**, NAME : "asd" will be missed out in the output. But what I need is **(0 + 0) / 2 = 0.** Means **if both score is 0, avg should be 0** and **if one of the score is > 0, avg = (the score which is > 0).**